# Popup windows in internet explorer 8 hang and never finish downloading

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, freeze

I am running Windows 7 x64 with internet explorer 8 and I noticed that popup windows in Outlook Web Access would open the window but would hang. The content would never display and the cursor would continue spinning forever.

Later I noticed that the problem was not limited to Outlook Web Access but basically any web site that opened a popup window (I think it only affects sites that are using Active X controls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called Microsoft about this problem and after about 2 hours on the phone I came up empty handed. They were unable to determine the cause of the problem and they suggested I rebuild the computer.

I did this and confirmed that the Outlook Web Access site worked as I installed applications to get my computer back to it's original state.

I eventually tracked the problem down to the source control program Vault (http://www.sourcegear.com/).

When I installed the client version 4.0.4 the problem occurred. If I uninstalled and rebooted the computer the problem would go away. Unable to believe it the first time I tried it again. There is no mistaking that this is the problem...

I am speachless...

**Update 12/1/2009:**
I contacted SourceGear technical support and they researched the problem and suggested I run the following commands to re-register some DLLs.

```
  regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"
  regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\actxprxy.dll"
```

The second command failed for me as the DLL is not on my system but the problem appears to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I too had this problem of 'personalized settings not responding' comingup never ending after Explorer 8 download.

Do this as advided Microsoft Help:

1. Resatrt the computer and keep pressing 'F8'
   2.You will get a balck screen with various options and select the one with ' start with latest working configuration'

This worked for me and the 'personalized settings not responding' did come up for a second and I was fine. The restart was fine and i had Exploreer 8 good to use.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i was having this problem on win7 32bit and running
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"
and
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\actxprxy.dll"

work for me